# Path mask on image Android Studio

Tags: android, canvas, path, bitmap, paint

everyone!

I want to load below image as bitmap in my app on Android Studio:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDvQN.png)
Then I need to add mask on this image which I must draw by path to get below image:
[masked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGi9d.png)
How I can do it?

I already have created DrawView class where I added first image as bitmap and added path object. In onDraw method my bitmap and path can drawing in canvas. Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `blendMode = BlendMode.Lighten` inside the source file of the image inside canvas.

```kotlin
        drawImage(image = imageBitmapMask,
            dstSize = IntSize(dimension, dimension),
        )
        drawImage(
            image = imageBitmapSrc,
            dstSize = IntSize(dimension, dimension),
            blendMode = BlendMode.Lighten,
        )
```